# How many users does Linux support being logged in at the same time via SSH?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, login, limit

I know Linux supports multiple users being logged in at the same time.

But what's the maximum number of users that can be logged into Linux at the same time?

I see there are there are 69 `tty` files (`ttyn` or `ttysn`, where `n` is an integer, such as `tty0`, `tty1`, `tty2`... ) in my `/dev` directory.  I assume that these files are the shells.  So I am thinking that this Linux system will support only 69 user logged in simultaneously.

Is my thinking correct?  If my assumption is wrong, please explain the users limit of Linux, including how it's implemented.

Also, how do I access the details of already logged in users?  I know commands **w**, **who**, but I am looking for sophisticated tools.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When logging in using SSH, you use a pseudo-terminal (a pty) allocated to the SSH daemon, not a real one (a tty). Pseudo-terminals are created and destroyed as needed. You can find the number of ptys allowed to be allocated at one time at `/proc/sys/kernel/pty/max`, and this value can be modified using the `kernel.pty.max` sysctl variable. Assuming that no other ptys are in use, that would be your limit.

`w`, `who`, and `users` are the canonical tools for accessing information about logged in users. `last` and `lastlog` also contain historical data.

Comment: could you please tell me  about the original tty limit , 
and where the information will be saved that is returned  by last command?

Comment: @usernaveen The maximum number of TTYs on modern Unices is largely limited by the number of virtual consoles you have available. The information shown by `last` is usually stored in `/var/log/wtmp`.

Comment: Probably the upper limit of an `unsigned int`.

Comment: If all connections are made by network, then the limit should be roughly about 64000.

Comment: @ott-- Not necessarily. You can have multiple interfaces, so you essentially have an infinite number of available ports.

Comment: @All: So why do we have that many(69) tty's(tty0, tty1,...) in /dev directory. What is the reason for including that many tty device files.

Comment: @usernaveen Many init systems try and cover as many use cases as possible when choosing how many TTYs to have available, as it costs very little (almost nothing).

Answer (score 0):

From a Debian machine like Ubuntu, if you check at

```
cat /usr/include/bits/typesizes.h | grep U32
```

shows that the number is  2*32 which is  around:
**4294967296**  users who can be added to the system

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pty/max
```

shows **4096** as the totals number of simultaneous number of ***logged in users***

Comment: CentOS is RHEL derived, not Debian.

Comment: yes you are right, a typo there @Edward